# What is the difference between reflectivity and reflectance?

Tags: terminology, definition, reflection

This question is in the context of solar reflections in buildings that cause glare. The two terms are similar but they have differences.

Answer (score 2):

Reflectivity is the square of the magnitude of the ratio of the reflected electric field to the incident electric field at a surface boundary.

Reflectance is the ratio of the total reflected power to the total incident power.

For an infinitely thick material, reflectivity and reflectance are the same.  For thin or layered materials, the reflectivity of the back surfaces contribute to the reflectance, often in a way that involves interference.  So reflectivity is a measure of the intrinsic reflectance of a material, whereas reflectance takes into account other factors like the thickness of the material and whatever other materials are present behind the surface material.

Answer (score 0):

Both *reflectance* and *reflectivity* have the *same* definition:
ratio of the reflected flux to the incident flux
(of power or probability).

But *reflectance* applies to *any* structure (it is the most generic term),
whereas *reflectivity* is reserved to an homogeneous semi-infinite structure (a *bulk* material).

From [ISO 80000-7:2019(en) Quantities and units — Part 7: Light and radiation](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:80000:-7:ed-2:v1:en):

> [7-31.3] **reflectance**: quotient of reflected radiant flux and incident radiant flux

The [CIE](http://cie.co.at/publications/international-standards) has the same definition for reflectance

> [[17-24-064](http://cie.co.at/eilvterm/17-24-064)] **reflectance** quotient of reflected radiant flux, $Φ_r$, and incident radiant flux, $Φ_m$

and

> [[17-24-093](http://cie.co.at/eilvterm/17-24-093)] **reflectivity**, <of a material>:
> reflectance of a layer of a material that is of sufficient thickness so that there is no change in reflectance with increase in thickness

###### Side note

They use the symbol $\rho$, but in my fields almost everyone uses $R$.